# DBT Cloud API to Extract run artifacts

Tags: dbt

Using DBT Cloud API, I want to extract the run artifacts and here is what my get request looks like. The response is 200 (success), but how do I download the artifacts.

```
res = requests.get(
            url=f"https://cloud.getdbt.com/api/v2/accounts/{ACCOUNT_ID}/runs/{JOB_RUN_ID}/artifacts/run_results.json",
            headers={'Authorization': f"Token {API_KEY}", 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        )
print('result:', res)
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, getting a "406 Not acceptable" response. Adding the header "Accept: text/html" solved it, now the json is in the response body. Strange enough, "Accept: application/json" did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're not extracting the result from the response. You have to call the following line:

```
data: dict = res.json()
```

Then you can operate on the response data.